# Only when testing: No mapping found for HTTP request

Tags: spring-test, request-mapping, spring-restdocs

I use [Spring Rest Docs](http://projects.spring.io/spring-restdocs/) in version 1.1.2.RELEASE

**The Test**

```
MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andDo(print())
                .andDo(document("index"))
                .andReturn();
```

**The API**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api")
    public ResponseEntity<String> apiWelcome() {
        final HttpHeaders httpHeaders= new HttpHeaders();
        httpHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("{\"api\": \"test1\"}", httpHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

When I run the application I can access "/api" in the browser and get the expected `{"api": "test1"}` response.

But if I run the test I get the following log entries:

```
c.i.crawler.testnet.measure.RestDocsTest INFO  Started RestDocsTest in 2.96 seconds
o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound WARN  No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api] in DispatcherServlet with name '' [main]
```

and the test fails because of `HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`.
What am I doing wrong?

**Application start**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { SomeController.class })
public class AppRUN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AppRUN.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: It's hard to say what the problem is from the snippets that you've provided. Can you share a complete example in a GitHub report or similar that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My test class was annotated as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=RestDocsTest.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Changing the annotations to the following removes the error:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
```